# How to fetch webpage title and images from URL?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I want to fetch website title and images from URL.

 as facebook.com doing. How I get images and website title from third party link.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [html Agility Pack](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx) this is a sample code to get the title:

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string url = @"http://www.veranomovistar.com.pe/";
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(wc.OpenRead(url));

    var metaTags = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//title");

    if (metaTags != null)
    {
        string title = metaTags[0].InnerText;
    }
}
```

Any doubt, post your comment.

Comment: How we get titles and images from third party URL with html agility pack.. can u give me example..?

Comment: @Abhishek - you might wanna read first the link given before asking. :) If you have problems on your codes -something like that....

Comment: @Reigel Ok I referring url.. let u know if any problem  - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you just need to send a standard HTTP request to the desired URL.  This will get you the site's markup.  You can then inspect the markup (either by parsing it into a DOM object and then querying the DOM, or by running some simple regexp's/pattern matching to find the things you are interested in) to extract things like the document's `<title>` element and any `<img>` elements on the page.

Comment: Hello @aroth Is it any way with json or web-service method? so it made faster way to retrieve..

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I'd use an HttpWebRequest to go get the page and parse the title out myself, then use further HttpWebRequests in order to go get any images referenced on the page.  There's a darn good chance though that there's a better way to do this and somebody will come along and tell you what it is.  If not, it'd look something like this:

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(<your URL here>);
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    //use the StreamReader object to get the page data and parse out the title as well as
    //getting locations of any images you need to get
catch
{
    //handle exceptions
}
finally
{
    if(response != null)
    {
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Probably the dumb way to do it, but that's my $0.02.

Comment: Disposing of resources should take place in a finally block. That way, even if an error occurs, the resource is disposed.

Answer (score -2):

just u hav to write using javascript on source body

for example

if u r using master page just u hav to write code on matser page thats reflect on all the pages
u can also used the image Url property in this script like that

khan mohd faizan